# Empty Div Needs to be 100% of parent

Tags: css, wordpress, position, height

I'm having a bit of a frustrating issue...I thought I found a few answers here but nothing as of yet seems to be working.

Here is an image to start off with:

http://www.shaunmbaer.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Melissliss_01.jpg

Then here is the html:

```
<section class="A">
  <aside class="B"></div>
  <header class="C">Title</header>
  <article class="D">Lorem ipsum...</article>
</section>
```

And the css as of now:

```
A{width:100%}
B{width:220px; height:100%; float: right; background= #fff url("foo") repeat}
C{width:450px}
D{width:450px}
```

I am using wordpress (this bit is a post), so all of the content is automatically generated. I need div "B" to be 100% of the parent div. It does not have any content besides a repeating background image (the site is responsive and this div will disappear at the next breakpoint).

I cannot position them absolute since I cannot give the article ("D") a fixed height (at least I think that statement is correct...)

Can anyone help or point me to somewhere that can? Preferably a CSS solution, but jQuery is a-ok at this point too!

Thanks a ton<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: You need periods in front of the class names in the stylesheet rule definitions

Comment: you're asking a question about your solution, without actually telling us what the real problem is (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Does B need to be 100% height? width? if it's filler, why use it at all, rather than make A take care of that using multiple, comma-separated CSS background properties? So in short: what are you *really* trying to do, because perhaps there's a better way to do it than your A{B,C,D} solution (my guess is: there is)

Comment: My question is: in the HTML structure above, how can I get the height of the aside (B) to have a height 100% of it's parent?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you *can* use absolute positioning for the B element, and specify 3 sides for the element to stick to:

```
.A {
    position: relative;
}

.B {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: So the answer was pretty simple, thanks to advice from Mike K. above (thanks for the advice on the XY question too!) I just got rid of the empty div (.b), and shifted the repeating background to the right of the parent (.a). Thanks everyone!